# Resize animated base64 with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, npmjs

Is it possible to resize an animated base64 with JavaScript on the client side.

Comment: Are you trying to scale the image or actually change the dimensions of the image?

Comment: I am trying to change the dimensions.  I don't want to use css.

Answer (score 0):

A gif is just an image, so yes you can use vanilla javascript to resize it, without the need for an npm package.